# Mobile websites: Facebook Like button

Tags: facebook, mobile-website, facebook-like

What method are you using for the Facebook Like button functionality for your mobile web sites?

On desktop sites, I've used the following:

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script>

                    <fb:like href="websiteurl" show_faces="true" layout="button_count"></fb:like>
```

However, this does rely on JavaScript libraries being loaded, which can be problematic for some mobile devices, especially since the Facebook JavaScript library is pretty big, and we're trying to keep the size of the site to a minimum.

The other option is to use an the iframe functionality, which seems to be the best way to handle it, however, some mobile devices don't support iframes.

We're supporting the following:
iPhone
Android
Blackberry
Windows Mobile

So looking to target as many of those devices as possible. I'm beginning to think the iframe is the best way to handle it, but am not sure how supported it is across the board for the devices above.

Thanks all

Comment: All platforms support JavaScript. It sucks on WM because of IE, but it works.

Comment: Well, most support JavaScript. The issue with it is how much JavaScript these mobile devices support. Their support is limited compared to the desktop browsers. Furthermore, the Facebook JavaScript library isn't exactly the most svelte of libraries, as we're trying to keep the overall footprint of the site to a minimum.

Comment: I really wish someone had the answer to implementing facebook 'like' on mobile web. I've asked here and on facebook developer forums and the answer is always the same - "look at iOS/Android API" - which completely ignores that we're asking about mobile web, not native apps. Facebook have even removed all mention of 'Facebook Connect for Mobile Web'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recently announced:

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/06/20/bringing-like-to-mobile/

Comment: Using the Built-in Like would mean you could trigger a Like action from any interaction, without loading a Like button. The post mentions mobile, but the Built-in Like isn't mobile only.

Answer (score 0):

There is unfortunately not a great way to do this at the moment. Facebook is working on it, but there is not yet a timetable for launch.